# Mobile Safari click event 'detail' property is always 1

Tags: html, mobile-safari

[UIEvent.detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) property should contain the current click count. MDN web docs [tells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail#Browser_compatibility) that the property is fully supported on all modern browsers, and it works correctly on all browsers I tested, except mobile Safari. I tried my Angular app and [MDN sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#Result) on IOS 12.3.1, and the `detail` property is always 1, no matter how many clicks were done. Is it mobile Safari problem? Any workaround (without counting the clicks manually)?