# DOM Event Detail Doesn't Increment on Angular Click Event

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to capture a triple click/touch event in Angular 7.

In the template:

```
<img id="logoImage" src="/assets/logo.png" (click)="clickLogo($event)">
```

In the component:

```
clickLogo(event) {
  console.log(event.detail);
  if (event.detail === 3) {
    console.log('Logo Triple Click!');
  }
}
```

If I click once, event.detail is 1. If I click 2 or 3 times quickly, each event.detail time is still 1.

I'm trying to implement the solution shown in the first answer here: [How do I listen for triple clicks in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480060/how-do-i-listen-for-triple-clicks-in-javascript)

Is there a way to make this work in Angular? I'd also be interested to know why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Do you test the app in Safari? Previously I [faced the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56441621/4858777) too.

Comment: Testing in Chrome.

Comment: In my case the `detail` property worked fine in Chrome. But anyway, I ended up with self click counting, because the `detail` didn't work in mobile Safari for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
let clickCount = 0;
let timeout;

clickLogo(event) {
  clickCount++;

  if (clickCount === 3) {
    console.log('Logo Triple Click!');
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }

  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    clickCount = 0;
  }, 400);

}
```

This will give you 400ms to tripple click and make clickCount 3, if you do not make it in 400ms clickCount will be reset to 0;

Comment: I've implemented this one here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyguni It works, but the setTimeout doesn't seem to clear the clickCount until there have been 3 clicks. I don't really understand why.

Comment: So swapping the clickCount check to be before setting the timeout makes this method work. If the click count check if statement is after the setTimeout, the timeout is only set after 3 clicks for some reason. I've updated my demo in the previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use rxjs fromEvent to handle angular events of stream to find triple click

```
 fromEvent(this.ref.nativeElement, 'click')
  .pipe(
    buffer(fromEvent(this.ref.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(throttleTime(400))),
    // if array is greater than 2, triple click occured
    filter(clickArray => clickArray.length > 2)
  ).subscribe(v => {
    console.log(v);
  })
```

Ref:learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffer.htmlxample:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-details

Comment: The console.log in you code logs every time you click, not only when you click 3 times. Even worse, it skips some logs if you click fast enough. I think he only wants to "do stuff" when there is a tripple click.

Comment: We can use filter operator to filter the event updated the answer

Comment: You are still left with a problem. It does not matter how long the interval is between the clicks if you use this approach. Every 3rd click will result in the console log, even if you leave 1 hour between every click (for example)

Comment: I have update the answer @Wolfyr and Thanks for pointing  my mistakes!

Comment: I've been testing this implementation and have noted that it takes 4 clicks to activate. If I do 3 clicks quickly it doesn't activate, but does if I subsequently do a 4th click, regardless of how long after.

Comment: It's worth noting that event the example here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffer.html requires three clicks to activate. It's like the first or last click activates the double click detection.

Comment: Yea i have added the ref to the answer Thanks. So it ks working only if you click four times?